# Only one Notifcation is clicable from a few

Tags: android, android-notifications

The problem is: in my code im sending 4 notification. But only one top notifacation opens my Activity another 3 do nothing on click.

Here is my code to send Notificaiton. I do it 4 times in my program.
The Notification ID is always diferrent.

```
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0, notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.element)
                        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(messages.get(messageCount).toString()); 

                Notification notification = builder.build();


                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                notificationManager.notify(messageCount, notification);
```

Please Help . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that android "eat" the same intents from pending intent.
You need to make them different using different extra and/or request codes

Comment: Thanks, i put different extra in intents